# how to update cell value of a row in dataframe and update the original dataframe in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to update the row of a dataframe and then update the original dataframe.
My dataframe looks like this:

`0  1  2
    0  2  4  6
    1  3  5  8`

I want the output like the following after updating column index 1:

       `0  1  2
    0  2  6  6
    1  3  7  8`

I tried with the following code but its not working

`df.loc[0,1] = '6'`

Comment: It works when I try the same code with the same DataFrame.

Comment: @ayhan Yes it is working now, but sometimes it just append at the end of the dataframe. Why is it so?

Comment: @SubodhD please add your results to the original question.

Comment: I solved the problem by using df.ix instead of df.loc